# How to disable calculation in str()

Tags: python

```
def LastDigit(num):
    last_digit = str(num)[-1]
    return last_digit
```

If I input 1235-4578-9899-2231 (without quotation mark), the function will return the last digit. The trouble is that if I input without quotation mark, Python will do automatic subtraction, instead of treating my input as a string in a whole.

Comment: Why without quotes?What are you trying to achive? Without quotes it is syntax not a number.

Comment: It will think that you are trying to subtract if it sees the "-" symbol outside of quotes, and so will duly subtract. It must be inside quotes to be a valid string, otherwise it's an expression. Integers don't have "-"s inside them.

Comment: It is part of my code. Sorry I don't put the entire code since it is too long. The "num" will be someone else input. I once thought about if I can convert the "num" to string, then users do not need to type " ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. `1235-4578-9899-2231` is code featuring subtraction operators. The interpreter cannot know that you mean it to be a string without quote marks.